# React Native Putting Fixed Component on top of Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

[image: A component takes over the top of the screen initially]

[image: B component takes over the entire screen, I would like to use FlatList here]

As shown above, I want to create this two-part screen where I can click onto both the A component and B component on the first view provided here. When a user scrolls B component, it may take up the entire screen and move over the A component. (A component does not move with the FlatList).

I'm new to react native and was wondering how I could create such behavior? I tried using absolute positioning and ListHeaderComponent inside the FlatList but didn't really get anywhere. Let me know if anyone has an idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like the following screen structure:

```
View
  Image
  ScrollView w/ trans background that goes to the top of screen
    FlatList with top padding to push it below the image
      Items in list
    /FlatList
  /ScrollView
/View
```

You could also see if react-native-parallax-scroll-view works for you as it looks somewhat similar to what you describe

https://github.com/jaysoo/react-native-parallax-scroll-view

Comment: Thanks Garret, that seems like it may work visually. My only concern would be that the <Image> won't be clickable in this structure. Also, how does Flatlist component behave when it's inside the scrollview? I understand flatlist asynchronously create its items in list whereas scrollview has to wait for all of its child to display.  Does scrollview + flatlist behaves as fast as flatlist? I will take a look into parallax.

Comment: I don't know of any issues with using a FlatList inside a ScrollView.  ScrollView now has the ability to clip sub-views that are not in the view port so I wouldn't expect any performance issues but it'd be worth testing.  Rather than the ScrollView, you could also try using a transparent header with a fixed height in the FlatList

Comment: @GarrettMcCullough One issue with having a `FlatList` nested inside a `ScrollView` is it always think you've reached the end and repeatedly trigger `onEndReached`.